# Delete one part of the String

Tags: java, string, get

I have this String :

```
String myStr = "something.bad@foo.us"
```

I want to get just the "something.bad" from `myStr` ?

Comment: will it always be an email adress and you want what's before the @ or is it just a substring you need?

Comment: It will be always email format

Comment: Then Jon Skeet's is the answer

Comment: Uhm...there's a [String API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), you know?

Comment: @talnicolas of course jon skeets answer is the answer :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to use `substring` having found the right index to chop at:

```
int index = myStr.indexOf('@');
// TODO: work out what to do if index == -1

String firstPart = myStr.substring(0, index);
```

EDIT: Fairly obviously, the above takes the substring before the *first* `@`. If you want the substring before the *last* `@` you would write:

```
int index = myStr.lastIndexOf('@');
// TODO: work out what to do if index == -1

String firstPart = myStr.substring(0, index);
```

Comment: Actually since we're talking about email - and as we all know legal email addresses may actually contain @s - one should really use lastIndexOf. Not that anyone would ever use such an email address, because pretty much every website ever contains code such as the above, so it probably won't matter in reality ;)

Comment: @Voo: Well, we don't really know the details of what the OP wants. Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: He said in a comment to his original post that it will always be email format.

Comment: @Voo: Yes, but not what he wanted to use the result for.

Comment: I just assumed he wanted to get rid of the domain and it's an easy to make assumption that no local-part may ever contain an @. But you could be right - he would have to clarify a bit.

Comment: @Voo : Actualy your comment helped me alot. I was wondering how to remove the last @ from the email and saw your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
String str = myStr.split("@")[0];
```

It will split the string in two parts and then you can get the first `String` element